# Possessive Adjective

Tags: possessive-adjectives

shell the ordinal number is used with possessive adjective without using of?. for instance

> my one friend leaves in Russia

instead

> one of my friends leaves in Russia.

what is make difference the above sentence.

---

Is there a difference when using a cardinal number with or without "of"? For instance:

> My one friend lives in Russia.

instead

> One of my friends lives in Russia.

What is the difference in meaning between the above sentences?

Comment: Please take some care and edit your question.  What is "shell"?  Do you mean "lives" instead of "leaves".  What is the "1." for Is this copied from a textbook?

Comment: "My one friend" means "the only friend I have"!